# Using class field in lambda as parameter Scala

Tags: scala, lambda

I am trying to create a constructor in which one of the methods could be passed. See my code:

```
class Foo(fooMethod: () => Unit, var x: Int, var y: Int) {
  def foo() = fooMethod()
}

class Bar(x: Int) extends Foo(() => {
  var test1 = x
  var test2 = y
  println(x + ", " + y)
}, x, 50)


class FieldDemo {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val bar = new Bar(40)
    bar.foo()
  }
}
```

The in this example `val test1 = x` does work, because it is a parameter of the `Bar` constructor, but `val test2 = y` does not work, even though `Bar` extends `Foo` and `Foo` has a field named `y`.

So my question is: why do you not have access to the `y` of the `Foo` class variable from within the function in `Bar`

---

**EDIT**:

When reading the answer, also look at the first comment by Matheusz Kubuszok and http://ideone.com/9yMpvw vs http://ideone.com/0fDxXe. The second link is the reason why the code in the first link should also fail. I imagine that edge case detection like this would make the compiler way more complex so I now indeed understand why they chose not to allow it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically your code is equivalent to something like:

```
val barFun(x: Int) = () => {
  var test1 = x
  var test2 = y
  println(x + ", " + y)
}

class Bar(x: Int) extends Foo(barFun(x), x, 50)
```

When you are creating your lambda, it only sees arguments passed into constructor - it is created within the scope of a constructor, so it has access to variables passed into it as a closure. It does *not* have access to Foo class as it is not its enclosing class. You can check it if you do something like:

```
class Bar(z: Int) extends Foo(() => {
  var test1 = x
  var test2 = y
  println(x + ", " + y)
}, z, 50)
```

You'll see that lambda will have no access to neither `x` nor `y`. Other test I tried in ammonite shows this:

```
class Bar(z: Int) extends Foo(() => {
  var test1 = Foo.this.x
  var test2 = Bar.this.y
}, z, 50)
cmd1.sc:2: Foo is not an enclosing class
  var test1 = Foo.this.x
              ^
cmd1.sc:3: Bar is not an enclosing class
  var test2 = Bar.this.y
              ^
Compilation Failed
```

As a matter of the fact, this makes sens. At the moment you are creating the lambda, class is not yet initialized. If whatever you do during class initialization had access to all those uninitialized `var`s, things could turn nasty.

Comment: Thanks for making clear why it doesn't work. It still puzzles me though why. In your last paragraph you explain why it would make sense, but if the lambda is created inside the class constructor, why would the `var`s be uninitialized? I thought that the constructor first calls the super classes constructor which initializes the variables of that class and only after that executes the constructor itself, therefore any use of the lambda would come after `var` initialization..

Comment: Or is it because the lambda is a parameter in stead of part of the constructor body?

Comment: Kind of. Let's assume that class parameters would be accessible to lambda. We could define it then like `{ val z = x + y; () => println(z) }`. It would add `x` to `y` store it as `z` and then create lambda, which would print `z` without calculating it every time... Except `Foo.x` and `Foo.y` are not yet initialized, because we called them before arguments were passed into constructor. Underneath parameters are getters returning value of some inner variable. Before constructor is called both are `null`. So we end up with `val z = null + null`. `NullPointerException` on constructor call.

Comment: Basically, we are evaluating expressions, which values are passed into constructor. If it was Java, I guess, it would behave as you expected (and end up with NPE), but someone took care to prevent that trap and defined the behavior the way you see it.

Comment: I don't quite follow your example. Could you provide a pastebin or something with the code?

Comment: http://ideone.com/O1L1AX - `Bar` is working because lambda has no access to the uninitialized parameters. `Baz` shows what would happen if it did.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141262/discussion-between-rik-schaaf-and-mateusz-kubuszok).